# subtracting reaction time lefthand from reaction time righthand

Tags: r

I`m a beginner R coder and Psychology Student, and looking for your help :)

My problem is probably best described as followed:

I did an experiment. Every participant reacted either with the right or left hand. What I wanna do is

1. Compute the mean reaction time per participant and used hand
2. Per participant: MeanReactionTimeLeftHand minus MeanReactionTimeRightHand.
   I have several responses per participant and put them all together using r.bind.
   My df looks something like this (numbers all random)

   | row | participant | RT | usedHand |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | [1] | 1 | 0.4 | right |
   | [2] | 1 | 0.5 | right |
   | [3] | 1 | 0.3 | left |
   | [4] | 1 | 0.6 | left |
   | [1] | 2 | 0.3 | right |
   | [2] | 2 | 0.2 | right |
   | [3] | 2 | 0.1 | left |
   | [4] | 2 | 0.9 | left |

I computed the mean reaction time per participant and hand using

```
Df %>% group_by(participant) %>% group_by(hand, .add = TRUE) %>% 
mutate(mRTperParticipantAndHand = mean(RT)) %>% ungroup()
```

As you can see I put it behind every legible row.

The df locked like this:

```
|row|participant|   RT  |usedHand|mRTperParticipantAndHand|
|---|-----------|-------|--------|------------------------|
|[1]|1          |   0.4 |   right|  mRT1right             |
|[2]|1          |   0.5 |   right|  mRT1right             |
|[3]|1          |   0.3 |   left |  mRT1left              |
|[4]|1          |   0.6 |   left |  mRT1left              |
|[1]|2          |   0.3 |   right|  mRT2right             | 
|[2]|2          |   0.2 |   right|  mRT2right             |
|[3]|2          |   0.1 |   left |  mRT2left              |
|[4]|2          |   0.9 |   left |  mRT2left              |
```

I do have major problems with the second step. Either I want another column with   MeanReactionTimeLeftHand minus MeanReactionTimeRightHand (with the same value for every participant)
Or a new df with  the column participant and MeanReactionTimeLeftHand minus MeanReactionTimeRightHand.
In my real df I have hundreds of RTs and several participants. So I`m looking for an automatic soloution.
I tried different approaches but none of them worked.
Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 1):

We could first group by participant and hand,
then calculate the mean,
then pivot the data and substract as desired:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  
df %>% 
  group_by(rowparticipant, usedHand) %>% 
  summarise(meanRT = mean(RT)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = usedHand,
    values_from = meanRT,
    names_prefix = "mean_"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(diff = round(mean_left - mean_right, 2))
```

```
  rowparticipant mean_left mean_right  diff
           <int>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1              1      0.45       0.45  0   
2              2      0.5        0.25  0.25
```